# how to get integer value of a z3 expression in c++

Tags: c++, z3

I have this piece of code here that adds two z3 bit-vector values in c++

```
expr Z3_LHS=z3_ctx.bv_val(0, 64);
expr Z3_RHS=z3_ctx.bv_val(8, 64);
output=Z3_LHS+Z3_RHS;
```

when I print the output I get

```
bvadd #x0000000000000000 #x0000000000000008
```

Please how can I get the integer value of this output expression which should be 8 instead of this long line. In other words I want to evaluate this expression to an integer value.

Comment: Shouldn't you ask the z3::solver to produce a model for that expression? See [this example](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c%2B%2B/example.cpp#L43-L65)

Comment: thanks alot... I m closer to what I wanted to achieve. However the result of the evaluation of adding the two bit vector values above gives #x0000000000000008 is there a way of returning this result  as a c++ integer  8

Comment: From the example I pasted, you should extract that from the model produced by the solver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of an odd thing to do, since you wouldn't use z3 to add constant numbers. But, here's how you'd code what you want using the C++ api:

```
#include <z3++.h>

using namespace z3;
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  context c;
  expr lhs = c.bv_val(0, 64);
  expr rhs = c.bv_val(8, 64);
  expr out = lhs+rhs;

  solver s(c);
  cout << s.check() << "\n";
  model m = s.get_model();
  cout << m.eval(out).get_numeral_int64() << "\n";

  return 0;
};
```

Assuming you put this in a file named `a.cpp`, here's what I get:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 a.cpp -l z3
$ ./a.out
sat
8
```

Comment: thanks :).. exactly what I wanted normally those 0 and 8 in lhs and rhs are replaced with variables that hold previously evaluated z3 expressions... so yeah just for simplicity I put them as defined integers for my question :)